# resetting blockchain and transactions won't clear stuck transaction

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, multibit

I'm using MultiBit Classic (sorry) and I have a stuck sent transaction due to low fee.

I keep resetting the blockchain and transactions in the application, but the transaction in question keeps showing up.

Should I be just waiting longer for the transaction to drop? Is constant opening MBC just making the problem worse?

Comment: related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/54447/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/53851/5406

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the real solution, but I exported my MultiBit Classic private keys and imported my address to blockchain.info wallet service.

Once I did that my transaction was confirmed within 24hrs.